# Someone copied my assignment without my knowledge but I am now accused of directly assisting them to copy my work

Tags: plagiarism

Someone copied my solution to an assignment without my knowledge, and now I'm accused of directly assisting them by allowing them to copy my work. I was given a formal written warning.

How do I prove that I did not give permission to anyone to copy my work?

I do not know the person. My lecturer held separate interviews with me and the unknown person.

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate on how the other person got hold of your assignment.  Hopefully, during your interview, you sound more competent than the other person.  That should help the teacher decides who is the original author.

Comment: The answers here may provide you insight : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/120834/72855

Comment: Is it really related to academia? This is a general comment nothing towards OP.

Comment: Can you prove you do not know the person? What "proof" do they claim indicating you abetting the other person? Did you do "work-for-hire" over the internet? Just a few questions to explore.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty hard (read impossible) to prove a negative. But it may be that you are really being accused of sharing the blame by being sloppy in keeping your own work private. Some places will treat that as cooperating, even if it is unintentional. If you *were* sloppy you probably have little recourse.

But one avenue may be open to you (among others). If the written warning is part of your permanent record you can ask to place a written rebuttal into the permanent record as well. If it isn't part of the permanent record, you can probably just move on. If you are questioned about it in the future, assure them that you really weren't at fault. But in most places, a single transgression is unlikely to end your career, especially if the official response was a *warning*.

Other options that might be open would be regular or ad-hoc judiciary panels that can adjudicate such things, though you aren't guaranteed success here.

And it is also just possible that the other person could take full responsibility for the act, leaving you in the clear.

Answer (score 1):

Send a written statement for the record that you did not cheat and that the details of the accusation were not shared. Send to teacher, his academic department chair, and whatever board or office sent you their written warning.  Make it clear in the letter everyone who is cc-ed and that there is a record to (your) file. Send letters certified mail (return receipt) or Fedex or the like so there is a delivery record.  That gets your objection on record.  And will definitely make it clear to teacher, etc. that you are strongly contesting the warning.